# How to get the centre of an object in direct x 11 C++

Tags: c++, directx

How to I obtain the centre of the objects I'm drawing in direct x 11? I'm having a problem when rotating the objects that they're rotating about their position, but their position is from one of the corners, resulting in a circular motion when rotating. I'm trying to rotate about the cente (origin)

I'm translating before rotating using the following:

```
setObjectWorld(XMMatrixIdentity());

setTranslation(XMMatrixTranslation(getPositionX(), getPositionY(), getPositionZ()));

setRotationAxis(XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
setRotation(XMMatrixRotationAxis(getRotationAxisVector(), delta));

setObjectWorld(getTranslationMatrix() * getRotationMatrix());
```

The outcome is this:

[image]

Comment: This is usually done as part of object design taking into account how the object should behave in the scene.  For very simple objects it can be done mathematically but for anything even slightly complex the object designer usually needs to include it in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation/scale should be done before translation